# Manipulate elements inside html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following template.

```
<script id="signoff-form" type="text/plain">
    <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
        <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input name="task_id" value="" id="task_id">
    </form>
</script>
```

Now I want to set the URL for the action and set the value for the task_id input.

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
var task = $(this).data('task-id');

var form = $("#signoff-form").html();
```

This handles the URL part ok however I cant work out how to set both.

```
$(form).attr('action', href).appendTo('body');
```

Your expertise would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the element by id or gen by the name attribute and update the value of the input element.

```
$(form).attr('action', href).appendTo('body').find('[name="task_id"]').val(task);

// or by id

$(form).attr('action', href).appendTo('body').find('#task_id').val(task);
```

```js
var href = '/abc';
var task = 'POST';
var form = $("#signoff-form").html();


$(form).attr('action', href).appendTo('body').find('[name="task_id"]').val(task);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="signoff-form" type="text/plain">
  <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input name="task_id" value="" id="task_id">
  </form>
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the response but neither of these append to body tag... there is no console error either.

Comment: I am still not sure how to set the value of `<input name="task_id" value="" id="task_id">` which i need to set dynamically along with the action. Your currently setting both attributes on the form tag.

Comment: dont hate me but it doesnt update the #task_id value, still remains blank?

tested -> `$(form).attr('action', href).appendTo('body').find('[name="task_id"]').val('testing');`

its as if its appending the form to the body and forgetting about the #task_id...

Comment: I was able to resolve using the following syntax - 

`$(form).attr('action', href).appendTo('body').find('#task_id').attr('value', task);`

Are you able to explain why .find() comes after the appendTo(), I would have thought you would want to set its value and then append to the body... or am I missing something :/

thank you

Comment: @mybigman :  the reference would change to the input element ... that's why I just added it after that